# How can I make the text resize downwardly in responsive mode?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want the `<p>` to spread downwards below the `<h1>` when resized in responsive. What happens now is, when I resize the window, when the `<p>` breaks, the `<h1>`'s position is adjusted to the top, I want it to be static.

```
`<h1>Title</h1>
<p>This is a long paragraph lorem ipsum sit amet dolor</p>`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add additional details to highlight your issue or add some image explaining the issue!

Comment: Isn't vertically and downwards the same

Comment: When I try resizing the width, the <p> breaks, and while it breaks, the position of the title is affected, they are both nested in the same <div>. I want the <p> to spread downwards below the title.

Comment: Unless there is something missing from your code, that cannot happen. This is why we generally require a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean spread downwards? Do you mean below the <div>

Comment: Yes Mark, below the title.

Comment: This would have been solved hours ago if you **had just made a codepen** - http://codepen.io/pen/